# How to get glyphname in GlyphTypeface?

Tags: c#

```
GlyphTypeface ttf = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(@"c:\windows\fonts\verdana.ttf"));
```

> while parsing ttf file im getting index,name,unicode ,arrays in opentype.js. Similarly, i need the name of the each glyph using c#

Comment: I undestand that your question is in reality quite short, but still, try to detail a bit more what you are trying to accomplish and what you want as a result. This could help other people looking or stuggling on the same issues as you. The more information you give, the high chance someone could land here and save some time ! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for could be [Face Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.facenames(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var faceNames = ttf.FaceNames
```

Comment: while parsing ttf file im getting index,name,unicode ,arrays in opentype.js. Similarly, i need the name of the each glyph using c#